# Getting string input crashes program

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, nodes, getline

I have this long piece of code here. I am trying to get string input for dnode 'word' and 'meaning'.
The problem is, on getline statement, when it is prompted to receive an input from the user, the program terminates. Simply crashes with error message:

`'file'.exe has stopped working. And, process exited after 'some' seconds with a return value 'somevalue'`.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<string>


using namespace std;

void create();
void add();
//void display();
void search();



struct dnode
{
    string word= " " ;
    string meaning = " ";
    dnode *right;
    dnode *left;
};

dnode *root =NULL;

string searchword= " " ;
string addedword= " " ;
string str;
int x;


int main()
{
    if (root==NULL)
{
    create();
    main();
}

else
{
    cout << "enter:";
    cin >> x;
    if (x==1)
    {
        add();
        main();
    }

    if (x==2)
    {
        search();
        main();
    }
 }
}

void create()
{
struct dnode *newnode = (dnode*) malloc (sizeof(struct dnode));

cout << "Enter the first word: " << endl;
cin >> newnode->word;
getline (cin, newnode->word);
cout << "Added";
cout << "Enter the meaning of " << newnode->word << endl;
getline (cin, newnode->meaning);
newnode->left=NULL;
newnode->right=NULL;
root=newnode;   
}

void add()
{
if (root==NULL)
{
    struct dnode *location=NULL;
    struct dnode *parent=NULL;
    struct dnode *temp=NULL;
    struct dnode *save=NULL;
    create();
}

else
{
    struct dnode *location=NULL;
    struct dnode *parent=NULL;
    struct dnode *temp=NULL;
    struct dnode *save=NULL;


    struct dnode *newnode = (dnode*) malloc (sizeof(struct dnode));
    cout << "Enter the word to add: " << endl;
    getline (cin, newnode->word);
    cout<< "Meaning: " << endl;
    getline (cin, newnode->meaning);
    newnode->left=NULL;
    newnode->right=NULL;

if ((root->word.compare(newnode->word)==0))
{
    location=root;
    parent=NULL;
    cout << addedword << "Word already exists" << endl;
    cout<< "Meaning: " << root->meaning << endl;
    main();
}

else if ((root->word.compare(newnode->word)< 0))
{
    temp=root->left;
    save=root;
}

else if ((root->word.compare(newnode->word)> 0))
{
    temp= root->right;
    save=root;
}

while (temp!=NULL)
{
    if ((newnode->word.compare(temp->word)==0))
    {
        location= temp;
        parent=save;

    }

    else if (newnode->word.compare(temp->word)<0)
    {
        save=temp;
        temp=temp->left;
    }

    else if (newnode->word.compare(temp->word)>0)
    {
        save=temp;
        temp=temp->right;
    }
}

location=NULL;
parent=save;



if ((newnode->word.compare(parent->word)<0))
{
    parent->left=newnode;
}

else if (newnode->word.compare(parent->word)>0)
{
    parent->right=newnode;
}

main(); 


}


}

void search()
{
int f=0; 
struct dnode *location=NULL;
struct dnode *parent=NULL;
struct dnode *temp=root;
struct dnode *save=NULL;

cout << "Enter the word to find: " << endl;
cin >> searchword;

if (root==NULL)
{
    cout << "Dictionary does not exist" << endl;

    main();
}

if ((root->word.compare(searchword)==0))
{
    location=root;
    parent=NULL;
    cout << searchword << " found" << endl;
    cout << "Meaning: " << root->meaning << endl;
    f=1;

    main();
}

else if ((searchword.compare(root->word)< 0))
{
    temp=root->left;
    save=root;
}

else if ((searchword.compare(root->word)> 0))
{
    temp= root->right;
    save=root;
}

while (temp!=NULL)
{
    if ((searchword.compare(temp->word)==0))
    {
        location= temp;
        parent=save;
        cout << searchword<< " found" << endl;
        cout << "Meaning: " << temp->meaning << endl;
        f=1;
        main();

    }

    else if ((searchword.compare(temp->word)<0))
    {
        save=temp;
        temp=temp->left;
    }

    else if ((searchword.compare(temp->word)>0))
    {
        save=temp;
        temp=temp->right;
    }
}

if (f==0)
{
    cout << "Word not in dictionary" << endl;
    main();
}


}
```

Comment: Why `malloc` in c++

Comment: Please try to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Suprisingly changing `struct dnode *newnode = (dnode*) malloc (sizeof(struct dnode));` to `dnode *newnode = new dnode;` and removing `cin >> newnode->word;` from `create()` the code works fine

Comment: And when you used your debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, and examine the values of all variables, what was the reason your debugger informed you why your program crashed?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `malloc` in C++ code.  `malloc` allocates uninitialized memory, so, for example, the `string` is never getting constructed in your struct.  In C++, use `new`.

Additionally, you loop by recursively calling into `main` all over the place.  You'll eventually run out of stack space if you do that.